# Running through Groupby with different {key:value} dictionaries

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

In the following code:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import random

sz = 50
df = pd.DataFrame({'Group': pd.Series(random.choice(['A', 'B']) for _ in range(sz)),
              'Key': pd.Series(np.random.randint(2, high=5, size=sz))})

dictforA = {2: 0.1, 3: 0.8, 4: 0.2}
dictforB = {3: 0.9}
```

...want to assign a new column called `Value` which is based on its respective dictionary. Missing values will be NaN.

The code:
`df.assign(Value=df.groupby('Group').apply(lambda x: np.where(x.index == 'A', dictforA[x.Key], dictforB[x.Key])))`

gives

`TypeError: 'Series' objects are mutable, thus they cannot be hashed`

Where am I going wrong?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You may create a mapper from Group to your dictionaries and use [`pd.Series.map`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.25/reference/api/pandas.Series.map.html)

```
mapper = {'A': dictforA, 
          'B': dictforB}

df['Value'] = df.groupby('Group').Key.apply(lambda s: s.map(mapper[s.name]))
```

---

```
>>> print(df.head(10))

  Group  Key  Value
0     B    3    0.9
1     A    2    0.1
2     B    3    0.9
3     A    3    0.8
4     A    3    0.8
5     A    2    0.1
6     B    2    NaN
7     B    2    NaN
8     A    4    0.2
9     A    2    0.1
```